# How can i configure Vim to use PHP style auto-complete for D comments too?

Tags: php, vim, autocomplete, d, comments

When I'm coding using PHP in [Vim](http://www.vim.org/) I can create a comment block like this:

```
/**
 * Mary had a little lamb.|
 */
```

When my cursor `|` is at the end of the sentence, I press return and get a new comment line this:

```
/**
 * Mary had a little lamb.
 * |
 */
```

Notice it has automatically added a new `*` character to continue the comment.

When I program using [D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_%28programming_language%29) in Vim and try the same thing, there is no new `*` added automatically and I get this:

```
/**
 * Mary had a little lamb.
 |
 */
```

Where do I need to add this in the D configuration to copy the PHP auto-complete of the comments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at `:h formatoptions` and `:h fo-table`.  The option you're looking for is `r`:

> Automatically insert the current comment leader after hitting
>           Enter in Insert mode.

You can create a file called `d.vim` in ftplugin in your vimfiles directory (where that is depends on your OS) and put your custom `set formatoptions` line there.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this section specifically, but this whole wiki page should have a lot of useful information. http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Indent

> File type based indentation
>
> This type of indentation is the most
> flexible, as it allows users to customize indentation per file type.
> For instance, the indentation scripts for C and C++ file types
> properly set the 'cindent' option, and there are very competent
> indentation scripts for Ruby, Perl and many other languages and file
> types. File type based indentation even works correctly with Makefiles
> without interference! If you plan on using file type based
> indentation, don't set 'smartindent' or 'cindent'. You may still set
> 'autoindent', since it doesn't interfere.
>
> The vimrc_example.vim that ships with Vim enables filetype based
> indentation:

```
if has("autocmd")
  " Enable file type detection.
  " Use the default filetype settings, so that mail gets 'tw' set to 72,
  " 'cindent' is on in C files, etc.
  " Also load indent files, to automatically do language-dependent indenting.
  filetype plugin indent on
  " ...
endif
```